# How I can connect Apache server remotely (http://149.4.223.238:8080) through my local machine

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, server, host

I am using Eclipse with Tomcat 8.0 and successfully run and deploy web application into Apache server.
Now my question is how I can access online apache host address app manager in order to deploy my application on this host [Remove Server Address](http://149.4.223.238:8080)

**tomcat_users.xml**

```
<tomcat-users>
<role rolename="admin-gui"/>
<role rolename="admin-script"/>
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<role rolename="manager-script"/>
<role rolename="manager-jmx"/>
<role rolename="manager-status"/>   
<user username="tom" password="tom123" roles="admin-gui"/>
<user username="malik" password="malik123" roles="manager-gui,manager-script,manager-jmx,manager-status"/>

</<tomcat-users>
```

I added this to server.xml

```
<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" address="149.4.223.238" redirectPort="8443"/>
```

**Context.xml**

```
<Context antiResourceLocking="false" privileged="true" >
  <!--
    Remove the comment markers from around the Valve below to limit access to
    the manager application to clients connecting from localhost
  -->

  <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
         allow="149\.4\.223\.238|127\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|::1|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1" />

 </Context>
```

I am searching from last 5-7 hours but still not understand.

Answer (score 0):

http://149.4.223.238:8080/manager/html

It looks like you might not have configured it yet.  that link also tell you how to set it up.  Also if you remote connect with that machine and access that site through localhost:8080/manager/html that should work too.

more details at

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html

Comment: I successfully access and deploy my web-app into app manager through **localhost:8080/manager/html** but I want to deploy web app into online host address.

Comment: ok then you just have to read that site and configure it so it allows access for you.

Comment: You might have to post your config files (those xmls) if you want help figuring out what went wrong.  take out sensitive info before you post it though.

Answer (score 0):

Your valve configuration is restricting access to IPs in the server itself, the public one and the loopback addresses

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
     allow="149\.4\.223\.238|127\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|::1|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1" />
```

So, if you want to allow access from your public IP (be careful with that, it's a security hole) you should include it on the regexp.
As an option, you can access it through an ssh tunnel (can be done with putty too)

```
ssh -L 8080:localhost:8080 some_user@149.4.223.238
```

Now it should be accessible from localhost:8080.

Comment: what is ssh? I am using Eclipse in Windows.